# Limit function not lipschitz.

Tags: functions

Is there a sequence of functions that are all lipschitz and uniformly continuous that converge uniformly to f and f need not be lipschitz?

Comment: If it is Lipschits, then it is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Let $f_n(x)=\min\{nx,\sqrt x\}$ on $[0,1]$